# Php code executes twice and causes "Constant allready defined" errors

Tags: php, litespeed

Recently my aplications started throwing errors of this kind:

> PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare {X Class} (previously declared in {X File: X line}) in {X File: X line}

After some investigations, I came to the conclusion that the PHP code is somehow being executed twice.

To make sure, I created a file with the following code:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);

define('SOMETHING', 'ITS OK');

echo SOMETHING;

die();
```

That is the entire code of the file. Yet sometimes, when requesting that file, the following error is beeing produced:

> PHP Notice:  Constant SOMETHING already defined in {Y File} on line 6

Do you know what kind of setting could be causing this?

The issue seems easyer to reproduce with fast consecutive requests but it might not be limited to that scenario, sometimes it seems to happen on a single request (but Im not considering this a fact)

Comment: You are requesting *that* file **directly**?! There's no other file involved which may `include` that file twice?

Comment: Do you use templates ? What's the engine of your server ? What's your Apache configuration (and your htaccess) ?

Comment: Well, you should add `if (!defined('SOMETHING')) {}` around the define, but still, check all your code, why its already defined.

Comment: maybe you include a file to that current file that has the same defined.

Comment: Its a separate file, that is the only code in the file, I am requesting it directly in browser. I created it specifically to test the issue with very little code in order to ensure there isnt some code error that would cause this. Its a Litespeed server, in htaccess I have some rewrites, gzip compression, expiresActive On and connection keep-alive.

Comment: can we see full code? something must be executing the script twice

Comment: That is the full code, those 4 lines. I know, Its weird. The hoster got back to me and told me the issue comes from the "proactive defense" module in imunify360. They disabled that module and it seems to work fine now.

Comment: Oh .. in that case may be better to close the question :) ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seem to appear because of proactive defense in imunify360. https://www.imunify360.com/proactive-defense . Disabling the proactive defense php module seems to resolve the issue.